# PS1: How do I echo colorcodes from functions that get executed in subshells?

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

I've never really touched bash before so it might be that the solution to my problem is obvious, but I can't wrap my head around it. I want to set my PS1 to certain values with certain colors. It works fine until I echo a color code from a subshell, then it gets messed up.

For example:

```
some_color='\033[01;38;5;196m'
PS1="\[$some_color\] $USER "
```

Works just fine. Assume I have a function called get_color that echoes the color code with the escape sequence,  my prompt prints the sequence \[\] in front of the username and the bash history is messed up when I hit arrow up a couple times.

```
some_color='\033[01;38;5;196m'
function get_color() {
  echo -n "\[$some_color\]" 
}
PS1="\$(get_color) $USER "
```

When I ommit the sequence it prints the right output but the bash history is still messed up.
When I use printf and the sequences \001 and \002 instead of \[ and \] it works just fine. Why does it not work with echo?

```
some_color='\033[01;38;5;196m'
function get_color() {
  printf \001$some_color\002" 
}
PS1="\$(get_color) $USER "
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use `printf` Instead of `echo`? It is decidedly the better option.

Comment: `\[` and `\]` are special syntax unique to PS1, to tell it to start or stop counting characters as printable for purposes of determining curser location / line wrap / etc; they have no meaning in any other context. There's no need to substitute something else in place of them -- you can just leave them out entirely.

Comment: ...and re: the printf-vs-echo thing, see *the POSIX specification for `echo`* advising that `printf` be used instead in the APPLICATION USAGE section at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: Leaving them out in the function leads to weird behaviour, I assume the shell isn't calculating the prompt length properly. Replacing them with \001 and \002 and printf works though.

Comment: I ended up using printf now but I'm still curious to why those sequences don't work with echo. Are they printf specific?

Comment: Nvm the documentation you linked me to explains that. Thank you!